# How to "compose" Iso's?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Here is my type:

```
newtype SaneDate = SaneDate UniversalTime
   deriving (Show, Eq, Typeable, Generic)
makeWrapped ''SaneDate
```

Now I need an iso with this type:

```
reprBuild :: Iso' (Maybe UniversalTime) (Fist SaneDate)
```

I did this:

```
reprBuild = iso
   (\ t -> First (SaneDate <$> t) )
   (\ sane_first -> fmap (^. _Wrapped) $ getFirst sane_first  )
```

But I have the impression I'm working extra-hard. Is there a (shorter) way of writing the `reprBuild` iso as a composition of things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of `lens` [have that built in](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#g:10):

```
reprBuild = coerced
```

Of course, this requires safe coercions which are only available since 7.10; for backwards compatibility [use a manual approach with `mapping`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38097055/745903).

Comment: Safe coercions have been around since 7.8. Does `lens` have too tight a bound in the CPP?

Answer (score 4):

The [`mapping`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:mapping) combinator lets you lift an `Iso` over any functor (in this case the `Maybe` functor):

```
reprBuild' :: Iso' (Maybe UniversalTime) (Maybe SaneDate)
reprBuild' = mapping _Unwrapped
```

We can also use the fact that `First` has a `Wrapped` instance to get the iso you want:

```
reprBuild :: Iso' (Maybe UniversalTime) (First SaneDate)
reprBuild = mapping _Unwrapped . _Unwrapped
```

You can also use the coercion isomorphism: [`coerced`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:coerced) but this will only work over newtype wrappers and needs ghc >= 7.10.

Answer (score 3):

Using [safe coercions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/Data-Coerce.html):

```
import Data.Coerce

reprBuild2 :: Iso' (Maybe UniversalTime) (First SaneDate)
reprBuild2 = iso coerce coerce
```

It type checks -- no other tests were performed.

Comment: Ok, this compiles and the tests pass.